# ActionBar fragment menu items. Putting them in front

Tags: android

I'm adding fragment menu items using the **onCreateOptionsMenu** successfully...

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater)
{
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.additional_fragment_menu, menu);
}
```

This additional menu above includes 1 menu item. What I need to do is put this menu item in front of all other existing items so that it appears first on the actionbar. Currently it appears last.

(This is an **android:showAsAction="always"** item I'm adding)

I tried adding it programmatically, but there is no option in the MenuItem object to allow you to specify icon and showAsAction flags.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Ok I cracked this myself with a pointer in the right direction from *EvilDuck*. And yes *dymmeh* you're right you can do this programmatically!!

What I needed to use was a combination of `orderInCategory` and `menuCategory`. Android seems to ignore `orderInCategory` if you don't have a `menuCategory` specified.

- I specified the category of every single menu item in my app by setting the `menuCategory` attribute value to `"system"`.
- My base menu items (the ones that are loaded via the `Activity`) I had to set high orderInCategory numbers, such as 10, 11, 12, 13 etc.
- When I then inflated and added the additional fragment menu xml with the same category and an `orderInCategory` value 1 it showed up as the first item.

Comment: I used for _back_ menu items that are inflated by the activity itself the category **'secondary'** and no category for the _front_ items of my fragments. It works (tested with emulators from 2.3.7 - 4.4). Order in category property not used.

Answer (score 6):

Try using "android:orderInCategory" attribute on menu items

Comment: weird... that helperd me reordering items in ActionBar

Comment: See my answer (below / above). Thanks for your help.

Comment: @EvilDuck Thanks. Not just menu items, it worked with menu groups too. I group all host activity's menu items in a group, then set `android:orderInCategory` to 999 (for example). And all items are shown at the bottom of the menu (after fragment's ones).

Comment: Can I set orderInCategory from code, not in xml? I am creating menu items programmatically, and they always show fisrt (before the ones created in xml), and I want them to show last..

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure where you're getting that you can't set the showAsAction option or the icon programmatically 
ex:

```
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    menu.add(Menu.NONE,  /** group ID.. not really needed unless you're working with groups **/
              0,         /** this is the items ID (get this in onOptionsItemSelected to determine what was clicked) **/
              Menu.NONE, /** ORDER.. this is what you want to change **/
              "Cancel") /** title **/
              .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_cancel)
              .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
}
```

Docs:

[menu.add(int groupId, int itemId, int order, CharSequence title)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu.html#add%28int,%20int,%20int,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29)

[setShowAsAction(int actionEnum)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html#setShowAsAction%28int%29)

[setIcon(int resId)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html#setIcon%28int%29)

Comment: Yes. He's using fragments + action bar which means he's either using API 11+ or the compatibility library for API 4+. Both of which have the methods I've described

Comment: Fair enough, although Compat library has different utility class methods for setting showAsAction on menu items.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that when looking at the code I use in my projects. Functionally the same, though. Just differ by return types and params.

Answer (score 0):

All is correct, just use below one line code in onCreateView.

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true);
```